# DocuSign Java JWT authentication fails, 400 bad request, consent_required

Tags: java, docusignapi

I am trying the official DocuSign Sample ["Java JWT authentication code example"](https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-java-jwt) but having trouble with it.

I checked out the project and just edited the `config.properties` file (added credentials etc.).
I am using a demo account, so auth-server is `account-d.docusign.com`.

But I always get a `400 Bad Request`.
I did some debugging and found out that the internal error code is `{"error":"invalid_grant"}`.

Can you please help me? The official sample project does not work for me...

---

edit:

I changed the clientId to the correct one, but now I get `{"error":"consent_required"}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fixed:**

1) (not so sure about, but...) *the sample project `eg-01-java-jwt` does not request scope `impersonation`, I had to add this line of code: `scopes.add(OAuth.Scope_IMPERSONATION);`*

2) I did not understand that I have to navigate the client/browser to the obtaining consent page first (because I thought it is the same user!!): `https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=token&scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=https://client.example.com/callback`

2.1) Make sure to register the `redirect_uri` in the Admin Tools first (Integration Key details).

2.2) Make sure to change `response_type` to `token`

2.3) Make sure to use `scop=signature%20impersonation`

Comment: very helpful, note my response_type was code not token.

Answer (score 0):

which Integration Key (IK) do you use? did you configure it in DocuSign Sandbox Admin? did you set up a private RSA Key and copied it to your code? All of these things can cause this issue. You need to also ensure consent for the user and making sure you have the correct userId (GUID) in your request. Can you double-check all of these and let us know what you find.

Comment: "ensure consent for the user and making sure you have the correct userId (GUID)" - yes, this is the part I am not 100% sure about. But there is no tutorial or some help with screenshots.

Comment: I used the DocuSign Sandbox Admin to create the RSA key: https://admindemo.docusign.com/api-integrator-key

Comment: Is the GUID the "User ID" shown in the admin demo under "My Account Information" in section "API and Keys" ?

Comment: User consent: I only have 1 user who is "DS Admin" (default)

Comment: there are few different things you need to verify. The userId is different than accountId. Consent is per user, you need to ensure the user you want consented to your app. The accountId is in the url for API calls.

Comment: also, confirm RSA Key is the private one and is property formatted.